# htaccess RewriteRule conflict : how does RewriteCond work?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've been trying and failing all day long yesterday.

I need to rewrite all urls to pass them as parameters to my front controller.

But I also need all urls starting with "admin" to be rewritten and passed as parameters to my admin controller...

Here is the code I tried. I know it can't work as is but I can't figure out how to do it...

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?uri=$1 [L]
RewriteCond $1 !^/admin
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ /admin/index.php?uri=$1 [L]
```

If someone can help me I'll be infinitely grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your RewriteCond before RewriteRule or put your admin rewrite before everything else.

As it stands right now, a visitor going to /admin is matched by the first rewrite rule and then that's it.

Your RewriteCond is actually applying to the second RewriteRule because of its position.

I would also change $1 to %{REQUEST_URI} and add QSA to the flags so query strings are passed properly.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?uri=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ /admin/index.php?uri=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This should work.

Comment: ok I get it. Still it's not working for me, I'm getting an "Internal Server Error"... misconfiguration?

Comment: It's says I'm an as* ;-) I's working now. I had a prefix in REQUEST URI since I'm using a RewriteBase that doesn't equal "/".
Thank you very much! Cheers!

Comment: No problem! One thing I almost forgot, however (it's late!!)... You will probably want to check if the request uri exists so images and what not aren't redirected to index.php... The -f flag can be used on RewriteCond:

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

Unless you want to pass it all through index.php :)

There's also -d which you can use if you don't want directories (that exist) redirected.

Comment: I'm aware of that, I didn't post that part in the question but it is implemented already. Thanks a lot for your concer